# Use rotary input with GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, input, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I am trying to use OnGenericMotionListener with GLSurfaceView but it never fires when i turn the dial of my watch.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
        @Composable
        fun StarMap() {
            val focusRester = remember{FocusRequester()}
            AndroidViewBinding(StarviewFragmentBinding::inflate, Modifier.onRotaryScrollEvent {
                Log.d("Rotary", it.verticalScrollPixels.toString())
                true
            }.onPreRotaryScrollEvent {
                Log.d("Rotary", it.verticalScrollPixels.toString())
                true
            }.focusRequester(focusRester).focusable()) {
                val myFragment = fragmentContainerView[0]
                myFragment.requestFocus()
        android.util.Log.d("Map", myFragment.javaClass.name)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Has anyone used the rotary input with GLSurfaceView on wear os app?

Comment: Have you tried with `focusRester.requestFocus()` instead of `myFragment.requestFocus()`

If you want to use `Modifier.onRotaryScrollEvent` you need to call `requestFocus()` on the `FocusRequester` you pass to your composable.

Comment: @YuriSchimke Your comment made it work for me. making the focusRester requestFocus(), if you post as and answer I will accept, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `focusRester.requestFocus()` instead of `myFragment.requestFocus()`

If you want to use Modifier.onRotaryScrollEvent you need to call requestFocus() on the FocusRequester you pass to your composable.